# Can the agent of reinforcement learning system serve as the environment for other agents and expose actions as services?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, intelligent-agent

Can the agent of reinforcement learning system serve as the environemnt for other agents and expose actions as services? Are there research that consider such question?

I tried to formulate the problem of network of reinforcement learning systems in other site of Stack network: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/111820/value-flow-and-economics-in-stacked-reinforcement-learning-systems-agent-as-r

So - is there some research along such stacked RLs? Of course, I know that Google is my friend, but sometimes I come up with the ideas that I don't know how to name them or how they are named by other scientists who have already discovered and researched them. And that is why I am useing stackexchange to give me some keywords for my ideas and I can myself explore futher the field using those keywords. So - **what are the keywords of resarch about such stakced RL systems, of agent-environment interchange in reinforcement?** learning?